# Transform a String into a censured String

Tags: java, string, char

I need create a method that get an String and return a new string that contains "x' character instead of the setence!

**input type:** I love icecream, and sand!

**output type:** x xxxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xxxxx

i have done these so far

```
public String censured(String input){

    char[] c= input.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
         if(c is a letter){ //dunno how to do these
             c = 'x';
         }
    }
    String censured = String.copyValueOf(c);
    return censured;
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: i donno how to do the if sentence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want print *x* and *,* you could simple implements your method to this:

```
public String censured(String input){

    char[] c= input.toCharArray();

    String censured ="";
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if(c[i] == ' ' ) censured += " ";
            if(c[i] == ',') censured += c[i];
            if(c[i] != ' ' && c[i] != ',') censured += "x";
    }
    return censured;
}
```

Tested and worked, good luck!

Comment: gonna test, just a sec!

Comment: perfect, what i want!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
System.out.println("I love icecream, and sand!".replaceAll("[a-zA-Z!]","x"));
```

Output

```
x xxxx xxxxxxxx, xxx xxxxx
```

Note : I added `!` to the regex to replace the `!` from string if you want to replace only alphabets then remove it from the regex.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/3ob8Lz)

Comment: it `Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.` read some docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll

Comment: @fabian for that we can change the regex to `[a-zA-Z!]`,updated my code.The OP is unclear here because the code OP showed says he would only want to replace letters

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Character.isLetter(char ch)](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29)